# How to push a helm chart to Harbor using Helm CLI V3.7.2 and Harbor 2.4.0-d4affc2

Tags: kubernetes-helm, harbor

Struggling finding documentation around this that works with specific versions of Harbor and Helm.

Ive tried adding my repo...

```
Helm repo add harbor https://myharbor.mydomain.com/chartrepo/myproject --username myusername --password mypassword
```

No issues so far

Then I try to push a chart in the local directory (.tgz file)

```
Helm push myhelmchart.tgz harbor
```

I get an error 'Error: scheme prefix missing from remote (e.g. "oci://")'

If I try

```
Helm push myhelmchart.tgz oci://harbor
```

I get an error 'dial tcp: lookup harbor: no such host'

I tried

```
helm repo add harbor oci://myharbor.mydomain.com/chartrepo/myproject --username myusername --password
```

I get an error 'looks like oci://myharbor.mydomain.com/chartrepo/myproject is not a valid chart repository'

If I just try and push directly and not use a registered repo

```
helm push myhelmchart.tgz oci://myharbor.mydomain.com/chartrepo/myproject
```

I get and error 'Error: unexpected status: 401 Unauthorized'

If I login first...

```
helm registry login myharbor.mydomain.com/chartrepo/myproject
Username: myusername
Password: mypassword
Login Succeeded
```

The attempt to push again

```
helm push myhelmchart.tgz oci://myharbor.mydomain.com/chartrepo/myproject
```

Same error 'Error: unexpected status: 401 Unauthorized'

My goal is to be able to push helm charts into Harbor and have them show up in this area...
[image]

Answer (score 16):

There are three options how helm charts can be pushed to Harbor

1. As you correctly found out yourself, you can install the helm addon [chartmuseum/helm-push](https://github.com/chartmuseum/helm-push) and use that to push Helm chart to Harbor
2. You create the Helm Chart locally with `helm package` and upload the `tgz` file via the Harbor UI
3. Since version 3.8 Helm support pushing and pulling Charts from OCI compliant container registries such as Harbor.

To be safe for the future, I recommend you switch to option 3, as Chartmuseum is already marked as deprecated in Harbor.

### Here is a quick rundown how to push/pull Helm Chart to OCI compliant Registries

#### Push Helm Chart to OCI registry:

```sh
helm registry login -u user container-registry.com
helm push harbor-1.7.4.tgz oci://container-registry.com/container-registry
```

#### Pull and Install Helm Chart from OCI registry:

```
helm pull oci://container-registry.com/container-registry/harbor --version 1.7.4
```

This is pulling to `tgz` file to your current directory.
Unlike with the common approach where you would first add a repo and the pull from it in order to be able to install a Chart you can do it all in one go with an OCI registry:

```sh
helm install myrelease  oci://container-registry.com/container-registry/harbor --version 1.7.4
```

Same procedure for `template` and `upgrade`

The `oci://` protocol is also available in various other subcommands.
Here is a complete list:

```
helm pull
helm show
helm template
helm install
helm upgrade
```

The Helm documentation has a [page with more OCI related examples](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/registries/).

Comment: Thanks for you response, for number 3, if you check my question, this is what I needed help with and could not get to work. I would just get the 401 unauthorized, even after successfully doing the helm registry login command. 2 is irrelevant because if you look at my question I am specifically asking about using the helm CLI

Comment: if you are using OCI registry chart are stored as images in your project not in the chartrepo. speciall namespace

The URL you provided  is wrong it should be like this for OCI. 
`oci://myharbor.mydomain.com/project/image --version x.y.z`

Comment: also you login to the registry so just keep the domain without the path e.g.`helm registry login -u user container-registry.com
`

Comment: are you using OIDC? If yes, get the CLI token you can't use the password you are using for the IDP. But if you have a successful login, you are doing it right.

Answer (score 10):

add harbor repo

```
helm repo add --username=username --password=xxxx myrepo https://harbor.xxxx.cn/chartrepo/xxxx
```

create chart

```
helm create  xxxxxx
```

lint chart in chart dir

```
helm lint .
```

package chart in chart dir

```
helm package .
```

install push plugin

```
helm plugin install https://github.com/chartmuseum/helm-push
```

push chart to repo

```
helm cm-push xxxxxx-0.1.0.tgz myrepo
```

Answer (score 8):

Found a solution, it does require a helm plugin but it works!

Download and install the helm-push plugin using the following command:

```
helm plugin install https://github.com/chartmuseum/helm-push
```

Ensure you have added your Harbor repo to helm using the following command:

```
Helm repo add harbor https://myharbor.mydomain.com/chartrepo/myproject --username myusername --password mypassword
```

*Note the /chartrepo in the url, this is important and not well documented but it is required to get the charts to show up under Helm Charts in Harbor*

Use the following command to push your chart to Harbor:

```
Helm cm-push myhelmchart.tgz harbor
```

Check Harbor project - helm charts

[image]

Comment: If this is a windows 10 machine you'll probably have to make adjustments to how you run the helm plugin install command. See https://github.com/chartmuseum/helm-push/issues/24 for solution to run this successfully on windows.